# Retrieve element size after changing innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm sure this is a frequently asked question, but I was unable to find an answer for the past hour, so here goes. I'm loading a table into the DOM via AJAX using jQuery, and I need to resize the DIV that encloses that table afterwards. jQuery allows me to write an event handler for the moment when the xmlhttprequest is complete, but that's obviously too early to read the size of the table, given that by that moment the browser hadn't had the time to render the thing.

As far as I can tell, I could probably use the mutant observer monstrosity, but I think that's overkill; I still hope there's some specific event that I can monitor instead of going all mutant. Help?

Comment: You can get it just fine ***after*** changing `innerHTML`

Comment: Duh! Yes, that is correct: http://jsfiddle.net/aK9sD/19/

I was using jQuery's lazy man's load(), and was checking for changes within that method's event handler. Apparently that's called before innerHTML is actually changed...

Comment: Use callback of function you use to place AJAX-response into DOM. If method does not have callback function - use promise, like:
`$('#someDiv').html(AJAXresponse).promise().done(function(){ ..do something after ajax and placing response.. })`

Comment: @dr.dimitru yes, I had switched to using the full ajax() call from jQuery as soon as that issue was clarified. Having said that, I didn't know about jQuery's promise mechanism, so thank you for pointing that out regardless.

Comment: @Gutza I'm happy to point you into right direction. Do you want me post this as answer, with more detailed example?

Comment: @dr.dimitru, thank you, that's not necessary.